# How to convert looped entries in tkinter from a string to a float?

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinter entry boxes are created using a for loop. When I attempt to `.get()` the entry values from them, it converts them to a float, then prints them, and I only get the final value converted! But I expect it to give me *every* entry input as a float.

Besides, if I leave the last `Entry()` box blank, I would get a `ValueError`.

Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *


homePage = Tk()

GameID_and_Entry = {}

for game in range(10):

    # create an entry box
    ratingsEntry = Entry(homePage, width=5, bg= "yellow")
    ratingsEntry.grid(sticky=W)

    # add this game's entry box to the dictionary
    GameID_and_Entry[0] = ratingsEntry


def ButtonPress():
    #Get every entry from the box, turn it into a float, then print

    for entry in GameID_and_Entry:
        R1 = float(ratingsEntry.get())
    print(R1)

#recommend button
recommendButton = Button(homePage, text="Recommend!", bg="yellow", command=ButtonPress)
recommendButton.grid(row=11, columnspan=2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably want a `list` instead of `dict`. Change to `GameID_and_Entry = []` and read [tutorial -Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: You keep overwriting `GameID_and_Entry[0]`